# Ambiguous reference on column when grouping by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm grouping a list of Bug reports on a known collection of users that are related to the report (that is, the user that is responsible for the report and the user that is currently assigned to it).

The Model `Bug` (AR, Rails 4.2.x) thus has, among others, two associations `assigned_to` and `responsible`, which are resolved to the foreign keys `assigned_to_id`, `responsible_id`.

Bugs can also be related to a project, which may also have a responsible user set, thus they also possess a `responsible_id` foreign key.

As we're grouping on both attributes from the report itself and the associated project, we want to include the associated project in the returned query.

I can then get a hash count of `<User> => count` through the following statement, grouping on the association name of the bug report:

```ruby
Bug.group(:assigned_to)
   .includes(:project)
   .references(:projects)
   .count
```

which correctly produces the desired result: A collection of Users (assignees) and the Bugs they are being assigned to.

For responsibles, the same query:

```ruby
Bug.group(:responsible)
   .includes(:project)
   .references(:projects)
   .count
```

yields an error, since the attribute `responsible_id` is both contained in the query by `bugs` and the associated `projects`.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "bugs"."id") AS count_id,
       responsible_id AS responsible_id
FROM "bugs"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."id" = "bugs"."project_id"
GROUP BY "bugs"."responsible_id"
```

If I instead group on the explicit attribute itself using `Bugs.group('bugs.responsible_id')`, I get a valid response, however in the form of `responsible_id => count`.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "bugs"."id") AS count_id,
       bugs.responsible_id AS bugs_responsible_id
FROM "bugs"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."id" = "bugs"."project_id"
WHERE <condition>
GROUP BY bugs.responsible_id
```

Is there a way to force using the association, but namespace the query as in the second query?

Of course I could process the result and expand it to the responsible users, however since the grouping is part of a larger querying functionality, I only get to manipulate the grouping identifier without extensive changes to the query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a fix for this now (in rails 4.2.4). This [will however become easy in rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c2d33c4abf01ec25b2d1528a7dae923aef5a30af).

If you absolutely must solve the problem now, you could patch `ActiveRecord::Calculations#execute_grouped_calculation` with the fix available in rails 5 for your app. Simply add an initializer at `config/initializers` e.g. `active_record_calculations_patch.rb` with the following (abbreviated) content. You can copy the original code from your rails version and then add the fix:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Calculations
    def execute_grouped_calculation(operation, column_name, distinct)

      ...
      else
        group_fields = group_attrs
      end

      # LINE OF CODE COPIED OVER FROM THE FIX
      group_fields = arel_columns(group_fields)
      # END OF COPIED OVER CODE

      group_aliases = group_fields.map { |field|
        column_alias_for(field)
      ...

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Great interim hack to get the fix working without further changes to the query structure. Surprisingly, a colleague of mine already went ahead that road in the meantime and fixed the issue ;)